# How do implement material without a texture image?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, bump

I am trying to implement the material on the object, such as the picture below, without the texture image. I've looked for a function called "Bump Node" to implement the material, but I'm not yet proficient in this, so it's hard to solve the problem. Is there a way to implement a material without a texture image only in a geometry configuration? Or, there is other ways for solve this problem?

*I'm going to make translucent material. So I don't think it's right to use texture images.

[image]

+(no texture image appears on my object.)
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Totally fine to use any image texture in any material. But what you want your translucent material look like? These bump can be generate by some built-in function, but there are still considered as "texture"

Comment: @Hikariztw Thank you for your answer. Updated post, please check the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image texture is just a storage of information. In your case, a normal map will suit for 100% sure.

I use the polymer gun grip material for it, you can find it [here](https://www.textures.com/download/substance0076/129488)

[image]

Basically you can do almost any materiel in Principled BSDF now.

You will need a **normal map** to fake the wavy surface. Connect that **image texture** to a **normal map node** to control strength. The connect it to `Normal` socket. The `Transmission` should be `1.0` in your case, and the main `Roughness` should be around `0` as well.

Comment: Thank you, but no texture image appears on my object.

Comment: It's definitely changing color, but it's smooth. There's no texture.

Comment: Updated post. Please check the post.

Comment: You didn't **UV unwrap** your mesh right? Use project UV option

Comment: and also, use Cycles for initial material check, then switch back to EEVEE to see where to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your kind. :)