# Why does the texture within the shader viewport look more distorted than the actual texture image?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, shaders, bump

Oviously, the texture image(in red rectangle) hasn't scratches. But why do the textures in the Shader Viewport appear scratches? I only used, `Bump Node`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The texture is (are?) not packed in the blend file... so... But looking closer, the UV map does not seem to be good (due to ngons)

Comment: @lemon Connecting only grid-patterned textures will cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the UV map problems, the nodes are illogical. You are connecting a normal map as bump. Normal map should be used with Normal Map node. It can be connected to the Bump node as Normal input, while a bump texture should control the Height of the Bump node. You have a texture named albedo connected to the Bump nodes Normal input - that makes no sense. Albedo textures might not be the best source for bump textures, but I will assume, that is what you wish to use it for.

This would probably make more sense:

[image]

You might want to consider lower bump distance values. 0.625 would mean 62.5 cm if you are working with metric units, while bumps on surfaces you might want to use bump maps for in a room sized scene might be somewhere around 1-10mm, so 0.001-0.01 for the value might be more logical. Of course, you might be modelling a surface of a planet - I don't know that. I am guessing the scale of your scene based on a normal map image in your screenshot and the texture name "floortileclean_normal.png".

Problems like you show in the picture might be caused by insufficient detail of a texture as well or insufficient bit depth, but it is hard to tell without testing them properly set up.

There is no red circle in the image, it's a rectangle.

Comment: Which the better texture for bump node? I was not aware that. I will make such as [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152551/how-do-implement-material-without-a-texture-image/152562?noredirect=1#comment259819_152562). Doesn't the grid texture I use suit my work?

Comment: Also, another texture of grid-texture isn't be `Invert`. This is because it has to be extruded. Or, is it fine if Invert effect is applied to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH23M.png) texture?

Comment: I have followed your reply to my work, but I don't see any [textures](https://opengameart.org/content/tile-textures-0).

Comment: Ah! It's normal. There's no blemish. However, if you connect the [second texture](https://www.textures.com/download/substance0076/129488) to the `Height` socket in the `Bump node`, the second texture does not appear. [Problem Image](https://imgur.com/a/PEZa6xH).